# Entity Framework in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I've used **EF** in Winform. However, I realize that I have been repeating the CRUD in every form. So, I'm trying to create a base form so that it can be inherited by others. I'm using `User Control` as my base form. **I would like to know how to create a base form**. Below is some sample code where I have to create save in different forms each and every time I create a new form.

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(lblProductId.Text);

        using (var context = new OrderDbContext())
        {
            if (ProductID == 0)
            {
                if (!IsValidProductName(tbxProductName.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Product Already Exists", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return;
                }

                Product products = new Product()
                {
                    ProductName = tbxProductName.Text,
                    ProductPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(tbxProductPrice.Text)
                };

                context.Products.Add(products);
            }

            else
            {
                var ProductToUpdate = context.Products.SingleOrDefault(Product => Product.ProductID == ProductID);
                if (ProductToUpdate != null)
                {
                    ProductToUpdate.ProductPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(tbxProductPrice.Text);
                    ProductToUpdate.ProductName = tbxProductName.Text;
                }
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Product Saved Successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        tbxProductName.Text = "";
        tbxProductPrice.Text = "";
        InitializeProductList();
    }


    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int SellerID = Convert.ToInt32(lblSellerId.Text);

        using (var context = new OrderDbContext())
        {
            if (SellerID == 0)
            {
                if (!IsValidMobileNumber(tbxSellerMobile.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Seller Already Exists", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return;
                }

                Seller Sellers = new Seller()
                {
                    SellerName = tbxSellerName.Text,
                    SellerMobile = tbxSellerMobile.Text

                };

                context.Sellers.Add(Sellers);
            }

            else
            {
                var SellerToUpdate = context.Sellers.SingleOrDefault(Seller => Seller.SellerID == SellerID);
                if (SellerToUpdate != null)
                {
                    SellerToUpdate.SellerMobile = tbxSellerMobile.Text;
                    SellerToUpdate.SellerName = tbxSellerName.Text;
                }
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Seller Saved Successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        tbxSellerName.Text = "";
        tbxSellerMobile.Text = "";
        InitializeSellerList();
    }
```

Comment: I would recommended you to move your data access logic  in to a different layer and use those expose services in your form rather than writing everything in your win form classes.

Comment: @Seminda I'm new to this. I don't quite get what you mean. Do you mean creating a new class and place those functions there?

Comment: Yes. You can start with that create separate class on your project add methods with  functionality you want. Then you can use those classes to call from your form events.

Comment: Read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384398.aspx to understand what I mean about layer.

Comment: @Seminda I've gone through the link and watched a youtube video about it. 


   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ncbr5axCabM I got the concept. However, I have 40+ tables. Does that mean that I have to create a class for every table?

Comment: If you required all of them yes. Otherwise you can do what ever required. Using this tool you can generate them easily  https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838/view/Reviews/2